# a word for the degree of how far an artillery system can send its missiles

Tags: word-request

Is there a noun in English that expresses the degree of how far an artillery system/weapon/installation can send its rockets/missiles/shells?

For example:

Whether we will eventually buy weapons from you depends on the _______________ of your weapons. We are interested in buying systems that would send missiles as far as possible.

Comment: Yes, it's called the "range" of the weapon.

Comment: @BillyKerr - But I am afraid it may convey a different meaning - like in "We have a wide range of weapons - from handguns to mortars".

Comment: I don't think "range" would be misunderstood in the cited context, but you could always use "reach" if it bothered you.

Comment: You could change the wording to remove any ambiguity. " . . . depends on their range", or "depends on the range of each weapon".

Comment: Technically, 'artillery' refers to a kind of large gun that fires shells (like very large bullets, either solid or filled with explosives or a mixture of explosives and metal). Artillery does not fire 'rockets', and we tend not to call the projectiles 'missiles' because they are something else.

Comment: Articles disambiguate, as well as context, word placement, singular or plural, etc. **_A_ range of _weapons_** could include pistols, rifles, mortars, howitzers, missiles, etc, but **_the_ range of _a_ weapon** is always how far it or its bullet, shell, bomb can go from the launch or firing point.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes, but that method isn't always reliable for distinguishing. For example: "I was impressed by the range of Lockheed Martin's howitzers."

Comment: @MarcInManhattan There is no other term: range of a weapon, weapon range and context is king. One can always come up what is, in dictionary or definitional terms, some kind of ambiguity but in practice that does not matter when there is only that technical term, And an editor would fix that if this were a press release, etc.

Comment: @Lambie I was generally agreeing with MH. (My first word was "yes", indicating agreement.) I was only noting an ambiguous case that could come up sometimes, as you acknowledge.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan - i know the K9 consortium (which includes Lockheed Martin, Hanwha Defense, Leonardo UK, and others) is to produce a development of the Hanwha K9 SP howitzer for the British Army. I didn't know Lockheed Martin have so far made any classic artillery weapons under their name. I know they make the HIMARS which is a kind of evolved 'Stalin Organ' rocket launcher system. Anyhow, I'd say 'Yes, the range is amazing! 54 kilometres!'

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That may be right; I might have been thinking of "rocket artillery" when I used LM as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in a comment, this is called the munition's "range". From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/range):

> the horizontal distance to which a projectile can be propelled

If you think that that word might get confused with another meaning (as you suggest in a comment above), then you could call it the "firing range". (This distinguishes it, for example, from "operational range", which typically includes how far a platform--mobile artillery, aircraft, etc.--can travel.) If you think that "firing range" might be confused with something like "[shooting range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_range)", then (if appropriate) you could say "effective firing range", which is even more limited.

Comment: Thank you! You've just nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a little extra detail, as well as simply "range" one might also quote "effective range". In fact, it would be normal to specify the latter instead of the former.

The first would usually refer to the maximum distance a gun might hurl its projectile, plain and simple. By contrast the second would refer to the maximum distance the gun could hurl the projectile and have a meaningful  effect on the target. For projectiles that rely on kinetic energy for effect -- from a simple musket ball, or handgun bullet, all the way to advanced anti-armour weaponry such as APFSDS rounds -- the effective range is the only one worth bothering about, and is very much less than the range.

Comment: Good point. Thank you!